# when i introduced yield in code it doesn't work in python

Tags: python-3.x, yield, yield-return

in below code, in if section of permute function. If i try to use yield it doesn't work but if i use print it works? can someone what's wrong with code?
Thanks in Advance!

```
def permute(li,l,r):
    if l==r:
        ele = ''.join(li)
        print(ele)
        yield ele
    else:
        for i in range(l,r+1):
            #print(i)
            li[i],li[l]=li[l],li[i]
            permute(li,l+1,r)
            li[i],li[l]=li[l],li[i]

class Solution:
    def find_permutation(self, S):
        # Code here
        s = list(S)
        f = []
        for i in permute(s,0,len(s)-1):
            print(i)
            f.append(i)
        return f



if __name__ == '__main__':
    t=int(input())
    for i in range(t):
        S=input()
        ob = Solution()
        ans = ob.find_permutation(S)
        for i in ans:
            print(i,end=" ")
        print()
```

Comment: Please consider accepting answers when they solve your problem (checkmark on the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

When performing a recursive call of a function that yields results you need to use `yield from` before your recursive call.  Otherwise the data yielded by your recursive calls will be ignored:

```py
def permute(li,l,r):
    if l==r:
        ele = ''.join(li)
        yield ele
    else:
        for i in range(l,r+1):
            li[i],li[l]=li[l],li[i]
            yield from permute(li,l+1,r)  #  change here
            li[i],li[l]=li[l],li[i]
```